# CSS Focus code does not work when switching to HTML 5

Tags: css, html, focus, css-selectors

I have some code that I use to make my inputs have a nice background color when you put the mouse over them:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    input[type="text"]:focus
    {
    background-color: #bfd0eb;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This works great with XHTML 1.0 Transitional, however when I switch to HTML 5, if I click on "input2" it takes the focus off of the "input2" I click and always focuses on "input1" instead.  What am I doing wrong?   Thanks!

Comment: both are type="text" where is password input???

Comment: That's all there is for code... there is no password input, I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can't leave a comment yet, I have added your code to jsFiddle and it works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/kuWWg/1/

If you want it to be on hover you need to use the `:hover` selector instead of `:focus`
http://jsfiddle.net/kuWWg/2/

Comment: Turns out it was some stupid browser error.  I'll give you the answer though just cuz that's useful.